# VBA Add Series Overlaps data

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2013, Win 10

I've got two pivot tables I'm trying to display on one chart. (I can't combine the source data because it's too many rows.)  So I decided to add the series to a chart in VBA:

```
Sub createProductionChart()
    Sheets("ProductionChart").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
      s.Delete
    Next s

    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlAreaStacked

    'Add history
    For i = 2 To 41
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("History Pivot").Cells(6, i)) Then
            Exit For
        End If


        Set tSeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        tSeries.XValues = Worksheets("History Pivot").Range("$A$7:$A$300")
        tSeries.Values = Worksheets("History Pivot").Range(Cells(7, i).Address, Cells(300, i).Address)
        tSeries.Name = Worksheets("History Pivot").Cells(6, i).Value
    Next i
     ' add forecast:
    For j = 2 To 200
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(7, j)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Set tSeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        tSeries.XValues = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Range("$A$8:$A$300")
        tSeries.Values = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Range(Cells(8, j).Address, Cells(300, j).Address)
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(6, j)) Then
            yr = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(6, j - 1).Value
        Else
            yr = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(6, j).Value
        End If
        tSeries.Name = yr & " " & Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(7, j).Value
    Next j



End Sub
```

The source data series are disjoint in X (they are dates, and the two charts represent, as named, history and forecast data).
XL just piles them on top of each other:
[image]

The "forecast" data should be on the right of the History.

As requested, sample of source data - they are huge, so only the upper left corner is shown:
History:
[image]

Forecast:
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you upload screen-shots of both PIVOT tables data that build this chart ? It will help to understand better (or eliminate some causes to this chart behavior)

Comment: check my answer and code below

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Forecast is sitting on top of the History is because the ***Stacked Area chart*** is always aligning it's data based on the order of the data (even if the values of your range are in the future).

You need to add all the dates in your History also to your forecast XValues  (and it's like they are having a value of 0 ).

I am not sure I am clear, let me know if you need more clarifications.

Anyway, try the code below, it worked with the testing I did on my workbook and chart:

```
Sub createProductionChart()

Dim Rng_Hisotry         As Range
Dim Rng_Forecast        As Range
Dim Rng_Combined        As Range

Sheets("ProductionChart").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
  s.Delete
Next s

ActiveChart.ChartType = xlAreaStacked

Set Rng_Hisotry = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Range("$A$8:$A$300")
Set Rng_Forecast = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Range("$A$8:$A$300")

' add History with Forecast Range >> so the forecast data will start 
' from the correct position on the chart
Set Rng_Combined = Range(Rng_Hisotry.Address & ":" & Rng_Forecast.Address)

' Add History
For i = 2 To 41
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("History Pivot").Cells(6, i)) Then
        Exit For
    End If

    Set tSeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    tSeries.XValues = Rng_Hisotry
    tSeries.Values = Worksheets("History Pivot").Range(Cells(7, i).Address, Cells(300, i).Address)
    tSeries.Name = Worksheets("History Pivot").Cells(6, i).Value
Next i

' Add Forecast
For j = 2 To 200
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(7, j)) Then
        Exit For
    End If

    Set tSeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    tSeries.XValues = Rng_Combined
    tSeries.Values = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Range(Cells(8, j).Address, Cells(300, j).Address)

    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(6, j)) Then
        yr = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(6, j - 1).Value
    Else
        yr = Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(6, j).Value
    End If
    tSeries.Name = yr & " " & Worksheets("Forecast Pivot").Cells(7, j).Value
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: I had a feeling that this was the problem.  I appreciate the effort, but this is not working.  this "reverses" the problem, but appears to be close  - it only shows the "forecast" data range.

Comment: @Marc what do you mean "reverses" ? I have the whole chart, History and Forecast, don't you ? did you change the set the X-axis of the chart ? or is it in Auto ?

Comment: @Marc no comment ? I think the minimum you can do is answer questions that are suppose to help me solve your problem

Comment: Sorry - I just abandoned the entire approach, and addressed my root problem in another manner.